# Testing a login form with jest and the react-testing library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this login form in react:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Card,CardBody,Container,Form,FormGroup,Label,Input,Button,Col,Row,UncontrolledAlert
} from 'reactstrap';
import { AuthLogin, AuthContext } from '../API/auth';
import { InputType } from 'reactstrap/es/Input';

function useInput(type: InputType): [string, JSX.Element] {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
    const inputId = type === "text" ? "username" : "password";
    const input = <Input id={inputId} value={value} type={type} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />;
    return [value, input];
}


export default function Login() {
    const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
    const [username, usernameInput] = useInput("text");
    const [password, passwordInput] = useInput("password");

    const failureMessage = () => {
        if (state.login_error) {
            return (
                <UncontrolledAlert color="danger">
                    Login failed: {state.login_error}
                </UncontrolledAlert>
            )

        }
    };

    const submitDisabled = () => username.length === 0 || password.length === 0;

    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        const doLogin = async () => {
            await AuthLogin(dispatch, username, password);
        };

        e.preventDefault()
        doLogin();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col><h1>Login</h1></Col>
                </Row>
                {failureMessage()}
                <Card className="login">
                    <CardBody>
                        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <FormGroup row>
                                <Label for='username' sm={2}>Username</Label>
                                <Col sm={12}>
                                    {usernameInput}
                                </Col>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup row>
                                <Label for='password' sm={2}>Password</Label>
                                <Col sm={12}>
                                    {passwordInput}
                                </Col>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <Button type="submit" disabled={submitDisabled()}>Log in</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And I want to test authentication in my frontend testing. Here is one (passing) test I've written:

```
test('submits username and password', async () => {

    // ARRANGE
    const username = "myusername";
    const password = "pass1234";
    const mockLogin = jest.fn();

    render(<Login onSubmit={mockLogin(username, password)} />);

    const usernameInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', { name: /Username/i });
    userEvent.type(usernameInput, 'myusername');
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText('Password');
    userEvent.type(passwordInput, 'pass1234');
    const loginButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /^Log in$/i });
    expect(loginButton).not.toBeDisabled();

    // ACT
    userEvent.click(loginButton);

    // ASSERT
    await expect(mockLogin).toHaveBeenCalled();
    await expect(mockLogin).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    await expect(mockLogin).toHaveBeenCalledWith("myusername", "pass1234");
  });

});
```

I'm new to react and these particular frontend testing frameworks, so my questions are more conceptual:

- should I be testing the actual authentication implementation (as well as mocking)? (given the middleware unit tests do that anyway)
- if so, how do I accomplish that - when I don't mock, I can't seem to get the form to submit (unless I'm misunderstanding the feedback - when I screen.debug(), I still see the login form, rather than the authenticated page or a login error).
- mocking in this case doesn't seem to prove much other than mocking is possible - I'm not sure I see the point, other than ensuring the expected elements are in the page and enabled/disabled when appropriate. Is that the point?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not trying to answer your question, but your test might be passing but it's not testing the right thing. The `handleSubmit` function is an internal function and the `Login` component doesn't accept any props. The `onSubmit` prop you're passing in the test doesn't exist in the actual component. What your assertions are verifying is that you're calling `mockLogin` in the test itself when you pass it as a prop: `mockLogin(username, password)`.

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves I get what you're saying and that makes sense - I agree it's not testing the right thing. So I somehow need to be able to mock the actual handleSubmit function, is that the approach I should be taking here? If so, any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: You can't mock the `handleSubmit` function as that's internal to the component. However, you can mock `AuthLogin`, which is called by `handleSubmit`, and assert that's it's called with the right params.

Comment: Thanks again @juliomalves. So AuthLogin looks like this: export const AuthLogin = async (dispatch: React.Dispatch<AuthAction>, username: string, password: string) => {... . If I mock like this:  expect(auth.AuthLogin).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockDispatch, "myusername", "pass1234");, I get the following error: Expected: [Function mockConstructor], "myusername", "pass1234"
    Received: [Function dispatch], "myusername", "pass1234". I can't work out how to mock that first argument, any ideas??